# User points download per node instead of per file

Tags: files, userpoints

The [userpoints download](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_userpoints) module works great for people to buy credits for file downloads.  I have three CCK fields in a content type, but I would like to remove a single user point no matter how many of them are downloaded from a single node. Any ideas?

Comment: A simple rule, deducting one point when the node is viewed? This however will happen again when the node is viewed again.